# High-Quality Animations with SvelteKit - which Stack synergizes best?

Tags: user-interface, animation, three.js, svelte, sveltekit

I'm currently sharpening my frontend skills and thus searching for a good tech-stack to setup a nicely animated portfolio website. I will use SvelteKit and Tailwind, but depart from that, I really have no clue what technological synergy fits best for this kind of purpose.

Did quite some research and always came back to three.js, do I need more technology to create a clean, responsive and animated frontend? Or would you recommend something completly different? The goal is to make a good looking portfolio website for the project track of my last years, so the solution should be quite clean. Also I really don't mind the deep dive, if there is some kind of special approach that goes hand in hand with a lot of know-how.

Thanks in advance!

Tried lightweight animations and wasnt satisfied. Looking for stunning implementations synergizing with SvelteKit.